# Most idiomatic way to write elsif test in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a conditional that looks like this:

```
if some_variable == 'some_string'
  perform_action()
elsif !(some_boolean)
  perform_different_action()
end
```

Is it better to write the elsif as:

```
elsif some_boolean == false
```

From what I have read most prefer unless to if !(value), so I am wondering if it is more idiomatic to use '== false' for elsif statements.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `unless` is tidy _by itself_ but when coupled with an `else` case as in `unless a else b` (which is how you'd have to write this), I would say it's downright evil.  Go with `elsif !some_boolean` is my opinion. It's perfectly readable.

Comment: If you wish to avoid the `!` you could of course write `if...perform_action(); elseif some_boolean; else perform_different action; end`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that your first example is more idiomatic. 
You can drop the parenthesis to make it more *rubyesque*.

```
if some_variable == 'some_string'
  perform_action
elsif !some_boolean
  perform_different_action
end
```

`some_boolean == false` is syntactically correct, but uselessly verbose.

`unless` is common, but it's confusing when followed by an `else`. Also, there is no such a keyword as `elseunless`, only `elsif`.

Comment: Yeah, having double, triple, or quadruple and more negatives is bad. `unless (!(is_not_enabled !== false))` hurts to read, especially with an `else` clause on the end. I think this is a case where the negation can't be avoided, so embrace it, but don't get overboard.

Answer (score 1):

Would this suit your tastes?

```
if some_variable == 'some_string'
  perform_action()
else
  perform_different_action() unless some_boolean
end
```

For those who dislike the embedded use of `unless`, I think I'd use Ruby's explicit `not`, which is harder to overlook, to emphasize the negation of the boolean:

```
if some_variable == 'some_string'
  perform_action()
elsif not some_boolean
  perform_different_action()
end
```

I'm not a big fan of using equality or inequality checks for booleans, such as `some_boolean == false`.

Comment: Having "surprise" conditions like that is *exceptionally* annoying.

Comment: This is not very clear. If you're already inside an `if-else`, you shouldn't hide another condition as a statement modifier.

Comment: @tadman I personally find it pretty readable.

Comment: @pjs It's fine to have your own personal style, but I think this is misleading and confusing. You've buried the `unless` in there. When writing tests you want it **abundantly** clear how many different paths there are to follow so you can correctly exercise them all. A quick glance here would imply two, but there's actually three.

Comment: @tadman Tastes vary. Speaking as somebody whose first language was FORTRAN 40 years ago, I find Ruby's postfix conditionals very readable.

Comment: This is about idiomatic Ruby, so I'm going to steer towards a very straightforward, obvious approach. This trailing `unless` method only works if there's a single statement. It wouldn't work if there was more than one, making it less generally applicable.

Comment: @tadman Perhaps you'll like the second proposal better then.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for alternatives to if/elsif, I'd like to throw another option into the mix...

```
perform_action_if_this(some_variable) || 
  perform_different_action_unless_that(some_boolean)
```

Then, at the start of each of these methods, return false unless the appropriate condition is met.

If you're simply asking whether `elsif x == false` or `elsif !x` is preferred, I would say that `elsif !x` is better.

The brackets for `elsif !(x)` are not necessary.

Also, bear in mind that they are not the same - if x is nil, they will give different results.